# PHP PDO: get number of rows returned

Tags: php, pdo

I can't find a way of finding the number of rows returned, after scouring the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) and other questions. How can I modify my `fetchAll()` method?

```
class Product {
    var $count;
    public function fetchAll(){
        $this->query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table");
        $this->query->setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
        $this->query->execute();
    }
    public function next(){
        $this->row = $this->query->fetch();
        if (!is_array($this->row)) return false;
        foreach ($this->row as $key => $val) {
            $this->{$key} = $val;
        }   
    }
    public function getCount(){
        return $this->count;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $num_rows = count($rows);` voila, you're done.

Comment: Re your now deleted question, here's some [possible things to try](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44763/wamp-drupal-7-high-cpu-long-page-load).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `$rows = $this->query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); return count($rows);` after the `$this->query->execute();`
You can also use [rowCount()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: Thanks - I will use PDO's `fetchAll()` if I have to, but I'd prefer a PDO method. Sadly the manual says for `rowCount()` " returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement". (No SELECT)

Comment: @Jodes: `rowCount()` works fine for SELECT when using MySQL, try it and see.

Comment: If you count the number of records in the array after you're done selecting, you'll have that number. Why do people complicate simple things.. `rowCount` isn't always safe and in certain cases can return 0 when in reality you have rows that are > 0. Just count your array with records.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on *why* do you need the count.

If you want to know how many products you have but not products themselves, then **you have to run a distinct query.**

If you want products, then you need no dedicated method for count at all.